# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column name

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I hope you all are safe.........question! Can you help me out with this? I am lost!  Thank you! I highly appreciate it!

LogCat:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column name
at com.musicapp.android.musicapp.fragment_all_songs.readSongs(fragment_all_songs.java:64)
```

code:

```
            String[] projections = {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER};

    63        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    64        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projections,null,null,null);
            if (cursor != null){
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do {
                        Song song = new Song();
                        song.artist_Name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                        song.songTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        song.songSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE));
                        //song.SongCover= cursor.get(Integer.parseInt(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE));
                        song.genre= cursor.getString(cursor.g

etColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER));

                    song_list.add(song);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6782345/3818303). They might have the same problem you are having about invalid column

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change `MediaStore.Audio.Genres.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER` to `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER`?

Comment: Please explain. I did run the code before/after (crash before/work after).

Comment: I copied the exact same code, but logcat tells me it is the same error

Comment: Your code at a whole will not work simply because you are trying to Integer.parseInt string. I was referring to the lines 63/64.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: I updated the code! so all the above works(If anyone in the future needs help with the same thing)!!!